# Spring Batch: How to get ExecutionContext into an Excel RowMapper?

Tags: spring-batch

I know this may be an anti-pattern, but I need to log every item my Spring Batch app reads as it reads it, regardless of chunk size (there's no getting around that). But I need information from the previous step, and I don't see a way to inject the `StepExecution` in my `RowMapper`. Can someone tell me (with Java config) if this is possible? I even tried retrieving the `StepExecution` from the `ApplicationContext` directly, but got a no such bean exception.

This is how my RowMapper looks:

```
  @Component
  public class YearEndRowMapper implements RowMapper<DistributionItem>, ApplicationContextAware, StepExecutionListener {
    private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(YearEndRowMapper.class);

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    // Autowiring didn't work here
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public DistributionItem mapRow(RowSet rs) throws Exception {
        DistributionItem item = applicationContext.getBean(DistributionItem.class);
        // setters
    }

    // This never gets called
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
}
```

Following is how I instantiate the item reader:

```
@Bean
public Step yearEndStep(FileIngestErrorListener errorListener,
                        FileIngestItemReadListener readListener,
                        ItemReader<FundsDistributionItem> yearEndReader) {
    return createBaseStep(errorListener, "yearEndStep")
            .reader(yearEndReader)
            .listener(readListener)
            .listener(errorListener)
            .build();
}

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public ItemStreamReader<DistributionItem> yearEndReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['filePath']}") String filePath,
                                                                 @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['filename']}") String filename,
                                                                 YearEndRowMapper yearEndRowMapper) {
        PoiItemReader<DistributionItem> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setRowMapper(yearEndRowMapper);
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath + filename));
        return reader;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to log every item my Spring Batch app reads as it reads it

You can use an `ItemReadListener#afterRead` to log read items. This is more appropriate than doing it in the mapper in my opinion.

> But I need information from the previous step

You can share data between steps through the job execution context. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.ItemReadListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    public MyJobConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    ExecutionContext executionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext()
                            .getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
                    executionContext.put("prefix", "Listener#afterRead: ");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        MyItemReadListener listener = new MyItemReadListener();
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(2)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3, 4)))
                .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                .listener((ItemReadListener<Integer>) listener)
                .listener((StepExecutionListener) listener)
                .build();
    }
    
    static class MyItemReadListener implements ItemReadListener<Integer>, StepExecutionListener {

        private StepExecution stepExecution;

        @Override
        public void beforeRead() { }

        @Override
        public void afterRead(Integer item) {
            System.out.println(stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getString("prefix") + item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadError(Exception ex) { }
        
        @Override
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
        }

        @Override
        public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
Listener#afterRead: 1
Listener#afterRead: 2
1
2
Listener#afterRead: 3
Listener#afterRead: 4
3
4
```

In this example, `step1` adds an information (a message prefix) in the job's execution context. Then the listener in `step2` gets this information from the execution context. I didn't see that you needed an information from the previous step when I suggested to implement `ItemStream`. `ItemStream#open(ExecutionContext context)` gets the step execution context as a parameter and not the job execution context. Since sharing data between steps is done through the job execution context, the listener can implement `StepExecutionContext` and get access to the job execution context as shown in the sample.

Note how the listener is polymorphic, hence it is registered as an `ItemReadListener` and `StepExecutionListener`.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I'm having trouble still. I implemented `ItemStream` and returned an `ItemStreamReader` in my bean (which I'll show in my example), but the ` open(ExecutionContext executionContext)` method is never called.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. Hope this helps.